# Не выводится результат. Python

Tags: python

Дано натуральное число N. Определить количество его цифр, кратных z. 
Обычная простенькая задача в 1,5 действия, но мой код почему-то не приводит к результату просто продолжает запрашивать входные данные

**Мой код:**

```
n, z = map(int,input().split())
count = 0;
while n != 0:
    if n % 10 % z == 0:
        n = n // 10
        count = count + 1
print(count)
```

Comment: `sum(e % z == 0 for e in map(int, n))` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убирать последнюю цифру нужно всегда, а не только если сработало условие:

```
n, z = map(int, input().split())
count = 0
while n != 0:
    if n % 10 % z == 0:
        count += 1    
    n //= 10
print(count)
```